# Problem, why the mouse cursor position is totally wrong, after resizing the window?

Tags: xna, graphics, mouse, resolution, ui-design

I come here, because i'm trying to add some "menu" interface in my small XNA Game . I found on internet a nice library adviced by many devellopers. Till now everythink is ok, the problem is my C# code logic. I try to allow the player (user) to change the screen resolution . The resolution and screen are both of them change . The problem is about the "cursor" of my computer mouse . It's really weird, i don't why but the cursor of my mouse does not select the right elements .It's look like a gap persisted between the old window.

Here is the code i use, as you can see , very simple. And should be normally work. I hope you have some idea why . I'm lost :'(

```
void btnApply_Click(object sender, Controls.EventArgs e)
{
  Manager.Graphics.IsFullScreen = chkResFull.Checked;

  //Resolution set by default
  int w = 1024;
  int h = 768;

  if (rdbRes1024.Checked)
  {
    w = 1024;
    h = 768;
  }
  else if (rdbRes1280.Checked)
  {
    w = 1280;
    h = 1024;
  }
  else if (rdbRes1680.Checked)
  {
    w = 1680;
    h = 1050;
  }

  Manager.Graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = w;
  Manager.Graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = h;      

  Manager.Graphics.ApplyChanges();      
}
```

Here is the screen shot of my original screen ( 800/480 )
[image]
Here is the screen shot after change to the screen resolution ( 1280/860 )
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you resize your game resolution you need to update every single `rectangle` in your game (every button, etc) and multiply it by a proper scale, so that the "hitboxes" would work, which would be a lot of work. So, a smarter way of achieving the same result is simply by multiplying your mouse position by a `Vector2 scale = new Vector2(originalWidth / width, originalHeight / height);`.

So, for example, no matter the game resolution, if your mouse is in the middle of the screen, you will see the mousePosition as (400,240);

```
int GameWidth = 800; // the original game's width
int Gameheight = 480; // the original game's height

Matrix ScaleMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(
    (float)graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / GameWidth,
    (float)graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / GameHeight, 
    1f
    );
Vector2 Scale = new Vector2(ScaleMatrix.M11, ScaleMatrix.M22);

Vector2 mousePosition = ...; // calculate mousePosition as you normally do
mousePosition = mousePosition / Scale;

//Update the input in Game_Reset event
private void Graphics_DeviceReset(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (arcadia.manager.RenderTarget != null)
        {
            //These steps are already done by the manager on Graphics Device Reset.
            //Manager.RenderTarget.Dispose();
            //Manager.RenderTarget = CreateRenderTarget(); 
            arcadia.manager.Input.InputOffset = new InputOffset(0, 0, arcadia.manager.ScreenWidth / (float)arcadia.manager.TargetWidth, arcadia.manager.ScreenHeight / (float)arcadia.manager.TargetHeight);
        }
        Window mainWindow = arcadia.manager.Controls.First() as Window;
        if (mainWindow != null)
        {
            mainWindow.Height = arcadia.manager.TargetHeight;
            mainWindow.Width = arcadia.manager.TargetWidth;

        }
    }
```

`ScaleMatrix` should be the same matrix you use when using you call: `spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, ScaleMatrix);` to scale your sprites.

Comment: Thank's a looot ! I find the problem about the GUI , need add some code in Game_Reset event for update the input mouse position. But about calcul the scale for the spriteBatch you help me nice ;-)